# How to add a HOC into the middle of a component stack?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a stateless functional component that renders a timeline (of appointments). Its signature is:

```
function Timeline({loading, start, end, data}) { ... }
```

It gets its data via an ajax request. For this, I created a HOC. You can use it like this

```
// AppointmentTimeline.jsx
export default ajaxLoader({
    route: 'secret.url',
    data: {some: 'post data'},
})(Timeline);
```

Then I needed to add some controls to adjust the timeline date range. I did this with composition:

```
export default class TimelineWithPicker extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <InlineBlock>
                <AppointmentTimeline {...this.props} start={this.state.start}/>
                {/* controls here */}
            </InlineBlock>
        );
    }
}
```

All of this works great, but now I've realized my `Timeline` component has even more utility than I originally thought. I want to re-use the same component *and* controls but with a different data-source.

i.e., I want to wrap `Timeline` with a different `ajaxLoader`. The problem is that `TimelineWithPicker` now has `AppointmentTimeline` baked in.

What's the best way to make `TimelineWithPicker` more flexible such that I can render Timelines with different data-sources?

Should I pass the sub-component (`AppointmentTimeline`) in as a prop, or should I pass `route` and `data` in as props and construct new HOCs on the fly at render time? i.e.,

```
let {data,route} = this.props;
let TimelineLoader = ajaxLoader({data,route})(Timeline);
return <div><TimelineLoader ... /></div>
```

Is it expensive to create new components in `render()` like that?

Comment: What is the requirement of putting the creation of new HOCs in the render method?  Are the `data` and `route` props likely to change between renders?

Comment: @Pineda No, not likely at all.

Comment: Then recreating the HOC on every render is unnecessarily expensive in the same way as binding a click to `this` would be. In the same way as the latter, it'd be advisable to define the HOC in a location that is likely to be involved less, i.e. the constructor or an appropriate lifecycle method